# C++ Code insertion using antlr and the line directive

Tags: c++, translation, antlr

I am using antlr to translate a custom language to C++ code.
In this language, user can embed C++ code snippets between `$code...$endcode` directives, that gets inserted into the translated C++code as-is.

I have the following problem: When there is an error in the code snippet I would like the compiler to point to the source file rather than the translated C++ code.

I tried using line directives as follows, but it didn't work:

```
"foo.custom_laguage"
1 $code
2 ...some c++ code...
3 $endcode
```

gets translated to

```
"auto-generated.cpp"
42 #line 2 "foo.custom_language"
43 ...some c++ code...
44 #line __LINE__ __FILE__
```

This doesn't work, I think because #line directive modifies what gets written by the `__LINE__` macro later. How can I set line number back to the *actual* line number in the translated C++ code? How does antlr do this?

Here is what I want the auto-generated code to look like:

```
"auto-generated.cpp"
42 #line 2 "foo.custom_language"
43 ...some c++ code...
44 #line 44 "auto-generated.cpp"  //actual line in this file
45 ..some more C++ code ...
```

**edit:**  I just found out that there is a way to do this in C# language by using a `#line default` directive:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t.aspx
 But couldn't find anything similar for C++

Comment: I just checked what antlr produces (with C target) -  it does not seem to insert any line directives with the embedded code. It just inserts the file name and line number of the source as comments

Comment: Why do you ever want to set your file and line number to the *translated* file?

Comment: I want to do this to make debugging within these code snippets easier. User should make corrections to the source, not in the auto-generated code. I know this would make it necessary to always distribute the source file with the auto-generated code, but in my application, the auto-generated code need not be maintained. It is  compiled immediately, and the executable is used.

Comment: I understand why you would want to issue `#line 2 "foo.custom_language"` directive. I'm asking about the `#line 44 "auto-generated.cpp"` directive. Why would you want to use it? Auto-generated code is not meant to be read and debugged by normal users. Perhaps you can use it while debugging the translator itself, but in that case you probably want to switch `#line` directives off altogether.

Comment: Currently I do need to debug the auto-generated code too. The translator is still being developed, so it would be useful. I am not clear as to why turning off the line directive altogether will help me debug that.

Comment: Re edit, there is no equivalent in C++. I wrote my own [C++ preprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/c-plus) and although it would be trivial to add that, it's not included in the language.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question, but you're generating the `#line` directives yourself given `source-line` and `source-file`? I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with Antlr.

Indeed, `#line __LINE__ __FILE__` does nothing but assign the `__LINE__` macro to itself.

Because of the evaluation semantics of the preprocessor, you can't easily assign the numeric value of `__LINE__` to a macro. (You can only define a new macro to map to the macro `__LINE__` literally, returning its *current* value.) But why do you need that? Unless Antlr itself uses the `__LINE__` macro, you don't need to restore it to its previous value.

If it is an issue, the most straightforward solution would be to put the raw C++ code in separate `include` files and forgo the inline embedding. To prevent proliferation of header files, you could use a construct like

```
$code
#define USE_SNIPPET_FOO
#include "snippets.h"
$endcode

$code
#define USE_SNIPPET_BAR
#include "snippets.h"
$endcode
```

and in the header, a kind of reverse header guard:

```
#ifdef USE_SNIPPET_FOO
#undef USE_SNIPPET_FOO
class foo {};

#elif defined USE_SNIPPET_BAR
#undef USE_SNIPPET_BAR
class bar {};

#else
#error no snippet selected
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though, I was really curious to know if there was a way to revert `__LINE__` back to its actual value, after changing it with #line directive.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way. What you want is to evaluate `__LINE__` at the beginning of the `$code` block and pass the result into the preprocessor. But the PP uses lazy evaluation and only evaluates when generating code or using the expression as a condition. Code generation is useless because you can't generate a directive. Conditional compilation is useless because then `__LINE__` would be evaluated at the location of the `#if` inside the hack, not in the same file as the `$code`. So to me it looks impossible.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I will have to stick to jumping between files manually for debugging for now..