# Reset the C/C++ preprocessor #line the physical file/line

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have a code generator that's going to take some user-written code and embed chunks of it in a larger generated file. I want the underlying compiler to provide good diagnostics when there are defects in the user's code, but I also don't want defects in the generated code to be misattributed to the source when they shouldn't be.

I intend to emit `#line lineNum "sourceFile"` directives at the beginning of each chunk of user-written code. However, I can't find any documentation of the `#line` directive that mentions a technique for 'resetting' `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` back to the actual line in the generated file once I leave the user-provided code. The ideal solution would be analogous to the C# preprocessor's `#line default` directive.

Do I just need to keep track of how many lines I've written and manually reset that myself? Or is there a better way, some sort of reset directive or sentinel value I can pass to `#line` to erase the association with the user's code?

It looks like this may have been [posed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772342/c-code-insertion-using-antlr-and-the-line-directive), though there's no solid answer there. To distinguish this from that, I'll additionally ask whether the lack of answer there has changed with C++11.

Comment: Is your intention to provide code that is already pre-processed?

Comment: No, it's to generate more useful output from an input that provides some RPC interface definitions and higher-level control flow. An illustrative (if large) example input is [this](http://charm.cs.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/gitweb2.cgi?p=charmlu.git;a=blob;f=lu.ci;h=5d84a2f02a9d1e4d77767037b68078ff583bea57;hb=HEAD). Look for the `atomic` blocks for the user-written C++ code that will be emitted verbatim that I wish to reference. The output actually gets `#include`'s in other C++ source files and preprocessed and compiled as part of those.

Comment: Is it possible for you to emit the user code at the end of the file so that you don't have to switch the line #/file name back?

Comment: In that case, I don't believe there is a solution.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: I can emit much of the this code toward the end of the output file, and that definitely limits the scope of annoyance if some bits end up wrong, but doesn't totally eliminate it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Some compilers may have an extension that does what you want, but I don't know any.  And I haven't had a chance to read through the 2011 standards thoroughly, but there was definitely no such feature in C99 or C++98.  Tracking the physical line number and 'official' physical file name yourself is the only _portable_ option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A technique I've used before is to have my code generator output a `#` by itself on a line when it wants to reset the line directives, and then use a simple awk script to postprocess the file and change those to correct line directives:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
/^#$/ { printf "#line %d \"%s\"\n", NR+1, FILENAME; next; }
{ print; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to keep track of the number of lines you've output, and you need to know the name of the file you're outputting into. Remember that the line number you specify is the line number of the next line. So if you've written 12 lines so far, you need to output `#line 14 "filename"`, since the #line directive will go on line 13, and so the next line is 14.

There's no difference between the `#line` preprocessor directive in `C` and `C++`.

Comment: The syntax for the `#line` directive is `#line *digit-sequence* "*s-char-sequence*"` (or just `#line *digit_sequence*`).

Comment: @DavidHammen oops, indeed, I put them in the wrong order, fixed. I changed it to "filename" as being more literal. The version without filename is, I think, pointless, since the OP wants to switch filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the input to the code generator, "user.code", contains the following:

```
int foo () {
   return error1 ();
}

int bar () {
   return error2 ();
}
```

Suppose you want to augment this so it looks basically look like this:

```
int foo () {
   return error1 ();
}

int generated_foo () {
   return generated_error1 ();
}

int bar () {
   return error2 ();
}

int generated_bar () {
   return generated_error2 ();
}
```

Except you don't want that. You want to add `#line` directives to the generated code so that the compiler messages indicate whether the errors / warnings are from the user code or the autogenerated code. The `#line` directive indicates the source of the next line of code (rather than the line containing the `#line` directive).

```
#line 1 "user.code"
int foo () {
   return error1 ();
}

#line 7 "generated_code.cpp"  // NOTE: This is line #6 of generated_code.cpp
int generated_foo () {
   return generated_error1 ();
}

#line 5 "user.code"
int bar () {
   return error2 ();
}

#line 17 "generated_code.cpp" // NOTE: This is line #16 of generated_code.cpp
int generated_bar () {
   return generated_error2 ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20 there is [source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) that gives an interface to get the same info than `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` (and a bit more).

It is marked `constexpr` so it should be possible to fully replace the pre-processor code with it, and allows you to modify the information when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@Novelocrat,

I had asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772342/c-code-insertion-using-antlr-and-the-line-directive) before, and no solid answers were posted, but I figured out that if line directives are inserted in the auto-generated code that points to the user code, then this makes the auto-generated code **hard to relocate**. You have to keep the auto-generated and user code in the locations where the compiler can find them for reporting errors. I thought it was better to simply insert the file name and line numbers of the user code in the generated code.  In good text editors it is a matter of a couple of keystrokes to jump to a line in a file by placing the cursor on the file name.

Eg: in vim placing the cursor on the file-name and pressing `g-f` takes you to the file, and `:42` takes you to the line 42 (say) that had the error.

Just posting this bit here, so that someone else coming up with the same questions might consider this alternative too.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried what `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` give you? I believe they are taken from your `#line` directives (what would be the point if not?).

(A quick test with gcc-4.7.2 and clang-3.1 confirms my hunch).

Comment: The `#line` directive is explicitly documented as resetting exactly those macros. Because the preprocessor is a lazy evaluator, one can't 'save' them in a macro definition to be restored later, either.